# SwaggerHub mock response returns 201 despite missing fields in POST request

Tags: mocking, swagger, swaggerhub

I'm trying to mock a POST request at SwaggerHub based on the following definition:

```yaml
    post:
      summary: "Creates order"
      description: ""
      consumes:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: "order"
        in: body
        description: "New order"
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Order"
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Order succesfully created."
        400:
          description: "Order can't be created"
```

Model is defined as:

```yaml
definitions:
  Order:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        format: uuid
        example: d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851
      marketPair:
        type: integer
        format: "int64"
        example: "BTC_TRY"
      amount:
        type: number
        format: "int64"
        example: "1.3"
      price:
        type: integer
        format: "int32"
        example: "467"
      operationType:
        type: string
        description: "Type of operation"
        enum: 
        - "buy"
        - "sell"
        example: "buy"
      orderType:
        type: string
        description: "Order Type"
        enum:
        - "limit"
        - "market"
        - "stop"
        default: "limit"
        example: "limit"
    xml:
      name: "Order"
```

Every time I'm trying to POST bad JSON with missing fields or even with no JSON in body at all I'm still receiving 201 code which absolutely shouldn't be 201.

Is there something missing in my configuration or what changes does it need for SwaggerHub to recognise my specification and start checking if the payload matches the specification requirements for this endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mock does not validate inputs in any way. It simply returns the lowest HTTP status code from those defined for the operation – in your example, status 201.

From [SwaggerHub documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html):

> Note that the mock does not support business logic, that is, it cannot send specific responses based on the input.
>
> ...
>
> The mock generates static responses for each API operation based on its responses and the response media types defined in the spec.
>
> If an operation has multiple response codes, the mock returns the response with the lowest status code. For example, if an operation has responses 201, 202 and 400, the mock returns the 201 response.

You might want to file a feature request with SwaggerHub devs.