# SwaggerHub mock always returns the same id - is this expected?

Tags: mocking, openapi, swaggerhub

I created a very simple OpenAPI docs as I have just started learning about it.

This is the link: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/srki.coric/Shopping_Cart/1.0.0

There is a mock server however, my expectation was that if I do a POST request with certain data, that the response will contain that data, and that `_id` would be auto-generated, but the response is always the default one.

Is this the expected behavior or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Related: [SwaggerHub mock response returns 201 despite missing fields in POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50569368/113116)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. SwaggerHub mocks are static, not dynamic. The mock does not process input data in any way, it just returns a static response based on the response `schema`. See [How response mocking works](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html#how) in SwaggerHub documentation.